# querying large dataset based on criteria (use, void)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with lots of records. I'm trying to query it but having a very difficult time figuring out how to do it....

Here's a structure of a table

```
 ID     ItemID        ItemDate        ItemCompany      ItemRecord
 11153  1123          1/17/2016       Apple            Use
 11555  1123          2/17/2016       Apple            Void
 12345  1125          3/22/2016       AON              Use
 15667  1333          6/22/2016       Adobe            Use
 19790  1333          9/23/2016       Adobe            Void
 20394  1333          10/1/2016       Adobe            Use
```

So here's my issue. I'm trying to find only items that have been USE. So in this case my desired end result would look like this....

```
 ID     ItemID        ItemDate        ItemCompany      ItemRecord
 12345  1125          3/22/2016       AON              Use
 20394  1333          10/1/2016       Adobe            Use
```

APPLE has 2 records - one is USE and one is VOID - so when it's voided it's put back into the system - therefore it has not been used. ADOBE on the other hand - had USE then VOID then USE again means it's been USED now.

Is there a way for me to query only those records that have USE - however if they have VOID - check if they also are followed by 2nd USE? If they don't then don't show the record at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, I think you want to know if the most recent date has `Use` on it.  Here is one way:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.itemdate = (select max(t2.itemdate)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.itemId = t.itemId and t2.ItemRecord = 'Use'
                   );
```

You can also do this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(itemdate) over (partition by itemId) as max_itemdate
      from t
     ) t
where itemRecord = 'Use' and itemDate = max_itemdate;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `ROW_NUMBER()` `PARTITION`ing on the `ItemId` and ordering by the `ItemDate` to get the most recent entry for the item.  Then only pulling back those that have a `Use` `ItemRecord` for the most recent:

```
With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By ItemId Order By ItemDate Desc) As RN
    From    YourTable
)
Select  Id, ItemId, ItemDate, ItemCompany, ItemRecord
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
And     ItemRecord = 'Use';
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ID, ItemID, ItemDate, ItemCompany, ItemRecord
FROM tableName t1
WHERE ItemRecord = 'Use'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tableName t2
    WHERE ItemRecord = 'Void'
    AND t1.ItemId = t2.ItemId
    AND t1.ItemDate < t2.ItemDate
)
```